# How to change material icon shape?

Tags: javascript, css, icons, google-material-icons, material-icons

The 'warning' material icon's shape is a triangle, but I am looking for a square-shaped icon.

https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Symbols+Outlined:warning:FILL@0;wght@400;GRAD@0;opsz@48&icon.query=alert

It is available here - https://pictogrammers.com/library/mdi/icon/alert-box-outline/
but I don't want to add new fonts to my system.

How can I change the shape of material icons?

Comment: Your question is hard to answer in this state. It depends. 0: perhaps they forgot to list it in the search? 1: clearly there's no such shape in the first link your provided - so you're out of luck. 2: **edit** the font - if it's a font. There are plenty of tools to edit fonts. 3: find another icons pack that has the desired shapes. 4: How are you using this fonts in your project?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan 1. there is a warning icon, i.e., exclamation mark inside triangle. 2. I did not find such tool or any tutorials. 3. yes, second link has desired icon, but I don't want to use any other pack. 4. I am using Google's material fonts. 

Thank you for reply, for now I will use other pack as you suggested as not able to edit the font icon for existing library.

Answer (score 0):

I was once looking for the same solution, that is to change the shape/design of an icon but the I could not find a way to do that. Yes, you can resize it and change its color but to change the shape, I don't think there is a way to do that.

If you really don't want to use any other fonts, consider using this google icon: https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Symbols+Outlined:assignment_late:FILL@0;wght@400;GRAD@0;opsz@48&icon.query=assignment+late

However, I would suggest to make yourself comfortable with using different sources, don't just stick to one, you may get one icon that's really good at one place and anther from another place.

Other good sources for icons that I use when needed:

1. Boxicons: https://boxicons.com/
2. Bootstrap icons: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Actually, I was looking for edit the icon in existing pack.  Yes, I already know that I can use the icon from other source.
Thank you for suggestion.